# postgresql - running median of y-values over a range of x

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, median

I want to smooth noisy data by applying a running median filter.
All the solutions I found are doing the rank statistics on the row used to define the running window.

Remark: The function 'percentile_cont(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY num_value)' is not a window function and doesen't work for my problem.

This is what I have so far:

```
-- sample dataset:
drop table IF exists demo;
create table  demo(timest timestamp,value int);
insert into demo(timest,value)  values('2022-01-01 06:00'::timestamp , 25)
                                    ,('2022-01-01 07:00'::timestamp , 30)
                                    ,('2022-01-01 08:00'::timestamp , 298)
                                    ,('2022-01-01 09:00'::timestamp , 25)
                                    ,('2022-01-01 10:00'::timestamp , 22)
                                    ,('2022-01-01 11:00'::timestamp , 35)
                                    ,('2022-01-01 12:00'::timestamp , NULL)
                                    ,('2022-01-01 13:00'::timestamp , 30)
                                    ,('2022-01-01 14:00'::timestamp , 19);

-- from wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_Median:                              
CREATE or replace FUNCTION _final_median(anyarray) RETURNS float8 AS $$ 
  WITH q AS
  (
     SELECT val
     FROM unnest($1) val
     WHERE VAL IS NOT NULL
     ORDER BY 1
  ),
  cnt AS
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM q
  )
  SELECT AVG(val)::float8
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT val FROM q
    LIMIT  2 - MOD((SELECT c FROM cnt), 2)
    OFFSET GREATEST(CEIL((SELECT c FROM cnt) / 2.0) - 1,0)  
  ) q2;
$$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

CREATE or replace AGGREGATE median(anyelement) (
  SFUNC=array_append,
  STYPE=anyarray,
  FINALFUNC=_final_median,
  INITCOND='{}'
);


-- my try:
select *
  , avg(value) over w as avg
  ,count(value) over w as count
  , median(to_number( to_char(timest,'HH24'),'99')) over w as median_HOUR -- debug
  , median(value) over w as wrong_median -- debug: returns value@median_HOUR
  , median(value) over (w order by value) as intended_result 
   --produces error: cannot override ORDER BY clause of window "w"
from demo 
--  where extract(hour from timest) = 8 -- not relevant for my problem
  window w as (ORDER BY timest 
                RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '2' hour PRECEDING AND interval '2' hour FOLLOWING
               )
```

This is the result I want:

The 'Intended_median' is the median of 'value' over the window **w** which is defined as a time period.

```
timest                  value avg                 count median_HOUR  wrong_median intended_result
2022-01-01 06:00:00.000 25   117.6666666666666667   3     7.0             30.0        30.0
2022-01-01 07:00:00.000 30    94.5000000000000000   4     7.5            164.0        27.5
2022-01-01 08:00:00.000 298   80.0000000000000000   5     8.0            298.0        25.0
2022-01-01 09:00:00.000 25    82.0000000000000000   5     9.0             25.0        30.0
2022-01-01 10:00:00.000 22    95.0000000000000000   4    10.0             22.0        30.0
2022-01-01 11:00:00.000 35    28.0000000000000000   4    11.0             35.0        27.5
2022-01-01 12:00:00.000 NULL  26.5000000000000000   4    12.0             NULL        26.0
2022-01-01 13:00:00.000 30    28.0000000000000000   3    12.5             NULL        30.0
2022-01-01 14:00:00.000 19    24.5000000000000000   2    13.0             30.0        24.5
```

The median()-function selects the center of the running window **w**. Instead I want to reoder **w** on the column 'value' to calculate the median.

Comment: Why are you using the window `w` in association with the function `median()` if you don't want to select the center of the running window `w` ? You could use `median()` without any window, so that it relies on all the values of the `value` column.

Comment: link us to the specific page, not the entire wiki.

Comment: Your "intended" column is commented out, and apparently doesn't work. So how are we supposed to know what it was that you intended?  Show us the answer you want.

Comment: Edouard: I want the median of the values in the running window, which is defined by a time period.

Comment: jjames: I hope' is't clearer now what I need

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by creating a table with the contents of the running window

-- my sample dataset:

```
drop table IF exists demo;
create table  demo(timest timestamp,value int);
insert into demo(timest,value)  values('2022-01-01 06:00'::timestamp , 25)
                                    ,('2022-01-01 07:00'::timestamp , 30)
                                    ,('2022-01-01 08:00'::timestamp , 298)
                                    ,('2022-01-01 09:00'::timestamp , 25)
                                    ,('2022-01-01 10:00'::timestamp , 22)
                                    ,('2022-01-01 11:00'::timestamp , 35)
                                    ,('2022-01-01 12:00'::timestamp , NULL)
                                    ,('2022-01-01 13:00'::timestamp , 30)
                                    ,('2022-01-01 14:00'::timestamp , 19);
```

-- get the borders of the  x-range (== running window)

```
with win as 
  (
    select timest as timest_current_row  -- current row of w
       ,min(timest) over w as min_win -- lower border of w
       ,max(timest) over w as max_win --
    from demo 
    window w as (ORDER BY timest 
                RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '2' hour PRECEDING AND interval '2' hour FOLLOWING
             )
   )
```

-- "expand" w: 'timest_w' contains all timestamps within w

```
   , tous as (
      select timest as timest_w  
        , timest_current_row
        , value 
      from demo
      join win on timest >= min_win and demo.timest <= max_win
   )
```

-- get the means,

```
  , means as (
     select timest_current_row
        , percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by value) as mean
     from tous 
     group by timest_current_row
  )
```

-- mean is the mean of 'value' over a 4-hour running window of 'timestamp'

```
 select timest
    , demo.value
    , means.mean
 from demo         
 join means on timest =timest_current_row 
 order by timest
```